# "Featuring" content in a Django website

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I'm working on a new Django project, and the client wants to "feature" content on the homepage and a few other sections of the website. Content in this case could be a blog post, an event, a news story, etc. Each item would have a "start featuring" datetime and an "stop featuring" datetime.

I've done this a few different ways in the past, but wonder if anybody has any great methods of archiving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at the [contenttypes framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes)? You could set up a `FeaturedItem` model, with start and end datetimes, and a generic foreign key. This allows the relationship to be with any model.

If you heavily feature objects from particular models, look at the section on [reverse generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations).

Comment: That's actually one of the methods I've used in the past. The one usability problem we've ran into is the visibility of what's currently featured, but I'll probably just create a "read-only" view of all active the FeaturedItems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying something similar, using the contenttypes framework but the problem comes when displaying the relationship in the admin area. I've been trying to hack this together to simply show a checkbox with "Featured?" next to it.

```
class FeaturedContent(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I'm not yet clear on how to implement the checkbox.